# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: DBA Pro Tem Moderators]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats guys! Both of you deserve it, I think you can handle this extra responsibility very well.

Apart from answering, drachenstern is active in both meta and chat; Eric is actively watching all questions providing good comments and edits.

We need more people like you to make this site happen. Current area51 [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators) are not looking good, we need step on the gas.

I must mention these people; Brian, Leigh, Joe and Gaius are also actively participating and good candidates for moderator election.

I missed the action and new area51 makeover for almost one month, because I was hospitalised for viral fever. Now I’m good and expect my full support both of you and all beta participants.

Comment: I think that it's *too* early to say the current stats don't look good... honestly the whole benchmark for site's working will probably be off in the long run.

Comment: @xenoterracide no, atm we're in the prime exact middle of benchmarking looking like crap. We really need to get things moving.

Comment: WB Sandy, I do hope you're feeling better. Welcome to being the third pro-tem mod ;)

Comment: @drachenstern - thank you :) I'm good.

Comment: @drach well then you should ask yourself what is it people don't like. I think this site started off way more foobarred than it could have. With topics like SQL being under debate, and the name being database administrators... (which means SO should be programmers? but that's so confusing.... then what would be call programmers... sigh...). I think the benchmark is probably not going to be on target for stuff that took a while to get launched in the first place. but hey, that's me. What do I know? I have no idea how all the other site's look. I don't even know how Unix SE looks :P

Comment: @drach personal opinion if you can get SO and SF to migrate new DB questions here... it might help. but I doubt they will. Anyways 'grats to all the new Pro Tem's

Comment: @xenoterracide - I saw your [post](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154/where-to-draw-the-dba-db-developer-line/156#156), we have to sort this out and update faq appropriately. We have to migrate dba questions from SO SF, definitely top 4 questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=database%20version%20controll. I'v flagged some of them in SO, lets see...